# Django project with custom user model load fixture error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

I am setting up a new django(version 2.2) project and want to use custom user model. When I load fixtures data, it failed with error like below:

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixtures: insert or update on table "doctors_doctor" violates foreign key constraint "doctors_doctor_user_ptr_id_ba968804_fk_doctors_user_id"
DETAIL:  Key (user_ptr_id)=(1) is not present in table "doctors_user".

From django document - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project I realized I did 'python manage.py migrate' before changing AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py. So I tried to delete all tables and redo 'python manage.py migrate', but it still hit this problem.

Following are my code

settings.py

```py
AUTH_USER_MODEL='doctors.User'
```

models.py

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    fixtures_autodump = ['dev_users']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'doctors_user'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


class Doctor(User):
    personal_id = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    fixtures_autodump = ['dev_users']

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'doctors_doctor'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

dev_users.json

```
[
    {
        "model": "doctors.doctor",
        "pk": 1,
        "fields": {
            "date_joined": "2019-06-16T09:09:56.127Z",
            "email": "user1@localhost.dev",
            "first_name": "user1",
            "groups": [],
            "is_active": true,
            "is_staff": true,
            "is_superuser": true,
            "last_login": null,
            "last_name": "test",
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$nITgYnD9lKzm$cXGlthNYJDrrihQikgyh7HO5hm2fNvH71+fiCoMyIpY=",
            "user_permissions": []
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "doctors.doctor",
        "pk": 2,
        "fields": {
            "date_joined": "2019-06-16T09:09:56.127Z",
            "email": "user2@localhost.dev",
            "first_name": "user2",
            "groups": [],
            "is_active": true,
            "is_staff": false,
            "is_superuser": false,
            "last_login": null,
            "last_name": "test",
            "password": "pbkdf2_sha256$36000$ohIbxnbyKjNm$smg+FvfhT1cF1kLt93EDz/n5KyfkDupIgkihsNIHQS8=",
            "user_permissions": []
        }
    }
]
```

I expect loading fixture data can be successful, please help.

Answer (score 1):

I needed 2 records in my JSON file, one is User, and the other is my custom user. The pk value of these 2 should be the same. That's the way Django loaddata works for custom user. I make this change and it works.